# jquery parrend id for hiden selector click buttno span

Tags: jquery

How to hide exactly the same span after clicking on the span with id + number?

```
<span id="myid-1"></span>
<span id="myid-2"></span>
<span id="myid-3"></span>

<script>
   $(document).click(function(){
    /**   if click button <span id="myid-1"> **/
       $('[id^="myid-"]').hide();
   })
</script>
```

Span is an old trash can icon that hides the entire post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to hide each span element when you click on it. I noticed you're using an attribute starts with selector to select all spans with ID "myid-blank". You could try:

```
$("span[id^='myid']").on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide()
})
```